# Dart Result with TypeError Exception

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, generics, future

I have the following `Result` object:

```
class Result<T> {
  Result._();

  factory Result.success(T t) = ResultSuccess<T>;

  factory Result.error(T exception) = ResultError<T>;
}

class ResultError<T> extends Result<T> {
  final T exception;

  ResultError(this.exception) : super._();
}

class ResultSuccess<T> extends Result<T> {
  final T value;

  ResultSuccess(this.value) : super._();
}
```

I have a function that returns a `Future` with a `Result` object like so:

```
Future<Result<bool>> doSomething() {
    return future
      .then((value) => Result.success(true))
      .catch ((error) => Result.error(Exception()));
  }
```

I think I'm using **Generics** in a proper way, however, I get the following error:

```
type 'ResultError<DatabaseException>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<Result<bool>>'
```

How can I return an `Exception` using `Result.error`?

Comment: Your `doSomething` method does not return anything?

Comment: Return type of method and data is different doSomething returns data with  Future<Result<bool>> datatype but the exception you want to return doesn't match with method's datatype as exception has ResultError<DatabaseException> datatype.

Comment: `ResultError<DatabaseException>` derives from `Result<DatabaseException>`, not from `Result<bool>`, so they are incompatible types.  Also, I highly recommend not using `Future.then` and `Future.catch` and using `async`/`await`.  It will make it *far* clearer what your function returns.

Comment: @jamesdlin thank you for the suggestion, however, how can I set an specific return type, so that when I try to get a value when result is ResultSucees I get the proper result type without having to cast it?

Comment: Shoehorning the success return type with error types into a single `Result` is a bad idea, IMO.  Additionally, you'll still need a mechanism to tell whether a `Result` is a success value or a failure value anyway, which isn't very different from casting.  If there's only one possible type of failure for `doSomething`, then you could parameterize `Result` on both the success type *and* the failure type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error subclass should be something like this:

```
class ResultError<T> extends Result<T> {
  final Object exception;

  ResultError(this.exception) : super._();
}
```

The type `T` is for the data, not the type of the exception.

Comment: Even if you create it like `Result<bool>.error(Exception(...))`. (It has no way to infer the type otherwise.)